# Acumatica Customization: Add PO Nbr column to SO Line

Tags: field, customization, acumatica, dac

I am trying to create a customization to add the PO Nbr associated in the PO Link graph to a column in the SO Line. I know the link is made in the SOLineSplit table, but I am struggling with how to actually show that field in the SO Line. I have made a custom Usr field for PO Nbr, but not sure what I should be entering in the attributes (or DAC extension, whatever is the best way) in order to show the PO Nbr data from the SOLineSplit table.

Answer (score 1):

I remember struggling with this early on, so it's an excellent question.  The challenge is that you mention getting to the PO from the SO LINE, but an SO Line can be split across multiple PO's.  That's why you end up having to dig into the SOLineSplit for the link.  Let's take a look at the link from SOLineSplit to PO...

There are a couple of possibilities when you look into the SOOrderEntry graph.  The following code snippets show relationships.  Your SOLineSplit may have a direct reference to the PO/POLine as shown here:

```
PXSelectBase<POLine> selectlinkedDropShips = new PXSelectJoin<POLine,
    InnerJoin<SOLineSplit, On<SOLineSplit.pOType, Equal<POLine.orderType>,
        And<SOLineSplit.pONbr, Equal<POLine.orderNbr>, 
        And<SOLineSplit.pOLineNbr, Equal<POLine.lineNbr>>>>>,
    Where<SOLineSplit.orderType, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderType>>,
    And<SOLineSplit.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>,
    And<POLine.orderType, Equal<POOrderType.dropShip>>>>>(this);
```

If that simple path doesn't get you there, the more detailed path of an SO to a PO lies in the INItemPlan reflecting the demand of the SOLineSplit (via the PlanID) and then tied to POLine via POLine.PlanID = INItemPlan.SupplyPlanID as shown in the following snippet.

```
foreach (PXResult<POLine, POOrder, INItemPlan, SOLineSplit> res in PXSelectJoin<POLine,
        InnerJoin<POOrder, On<POLine.FK.Order>,
        InnerJoin<INItemPlan, On<INItemPlan.supplyPlanID, Equal<POLine.planID>>,
        InnerJoin<SOLineSplit, On<SOLineSplit.planID, Equal<INItemPlan.planID>,
           And<SOLineSplit.pOType, Equal<POLine.orderType>,
           And<SOLineSplit.pONbr, Equal<POLine.orderNbr>,
           And<SOLineSplit.pOLineNbr, Equal<POLine.lineNbr>>>>>>>>,
        Where<POLine.orderType, Equal<Required<POLine.orderType>>,
            And<POLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<POLine.orderNbr>>,
            And2<Where<POLine.cancelled, Equal<boolTrue>,
                   Or<POLine.completed, Equal<boolTrue>>>,
            And2<Where<POOrder.orderType, NotEqual<POOrderType.dropShip>,
                   Or<POOrder.isLegacyDropShip, Equal<True>>>,
        And<SOLineSplit.receivedQty, Less<SOLineSplit.qty>,
        And<SOLineSplit.pOCancelled, NotEqual<boolTrue>,
        And<SOLineSplit.completed, NotEqual<boolTrue>>>>>>>>>
        .Select(graph, poOrder.OrderType, poOrder.OrderNbr))
    {...
```

As you can imagine, you would have to set some rules around restricting an SO Line to a single PO, but that honestly would be more trouble than it's worth as the standard functionality is valuable in being more robust.  I would suggest either putting your link in the Allocations list (or *Line Details* in more recent versions of Acumatica ERP) or produce a smart panel popup to show all the PO links per splits of the current SO Line.